# Can i set a 2D array on C as (fixed)(dynamic)?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

i have another question. Can i set an array as [fixed][dynamic]?, the first value will be reader from a file ( numbers of sensors used by user ) and the other value will be a dynamic array [time of reading].

I was reading about 2D dynamic arrays, but i do not know if i can do this. Any advise?.

Thanks.

Comment: You can make a 2-D VLA: `int x[a][b];` where `a` and `b` are both variables.  Alternatively, you can use a 1-D array of pointers where each pointer points to an array of length `b` as the other posters suggest, although this is not the same as a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can...  Just declare an array of pointers.  Then you can use `malloc` and `realloc` to modify the subarray stored at each element.

```
struct reading * data[num_sensors];
```

But you're kinda talking about *both* the dimensions being dynamic.  You might need:

```
struct reading ** data = malloc(sizeof(struct reading*) * num_sensors);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can i set an array as [fixed][dynamic]?

Yes. You could achieve this by doing something likes

```
int *arr[fixed];

for (i = 0; i < fixed; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(length(i) * sizeof(int));
}
```

that `length(i)` will return the length of `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FIXED 20
int main()
{
    /*Array of integer pointers*/
   int *pi4_arr[FIXED]; 
   int i4_dyn_length= 0;
   int i4_ctr = 0;

   printf("Enter the dynamic length of array:");

   /* Make sure to enter this value greater than 1 or,  program*/
   /*  will crash at assignment before printf before the return*/
   scanf("%d",&i4_dyn_length);  

   for(i4_ctr =0; i4_ctr < FIXED; i4_ctr++) 
   {
       pi4_arr[i4_ctr] = malloc(i4_dyn_length * sizeof(int));
   }/*for(i4_ctr =0; i4_ctr < FIXED; i4_ctr++) */

   pi4_arr[0][0] = 1;
   printf("\n\npi4_arr[0][0]: %d",pi4_arr[0][0]);

   /*Make sure to call free before exit, to avoid memory leak */
   return 0;
}
```